# Google top 100 words searched for

Tags: google-search, analytics, search-engine

Is there any way to see the list of top words searched for on Google? I'm looking for a range of somewhere like 100-500 words.

The problem with [Google Hot Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends)/[Searches](http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?sa=X) and [Google Zeitgeist](http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/press/zeitgeist2009/) is that it shows *searches*, not *words*. Here's an example of why the latter is more important to me. Say I want to find out if a lot of people are using search engines to find recipes. You would think that I could look at the term "recipe" and find this out. However, this is not the case because "recipe" will only show me the results for people searching for "recipe" as a single keyword (e.g. they are looking for recipe sites). I'm looking for how many people are actually looking for recipes with queries such as "pumpkin pie recipe", "scones recipe", etc.

The problem with [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) is that it only shows you the popularity of a single term over time, or it allows you to compare it to other terms. This can't easily be used to for the scenario I presented above.

If this is not possible, I'm also looking for a way to do the opposite, that is, given a word, I want to know how popular it is. For example I would ask how popular the word "email" is, and then it would say something like 86, indicating that "email" is the 86th most searched word on Google.

The closest thing I found is [this page](http://historico.portalmix.com/english/keywords.htm) which claims to list the top 500 search words, but it doesn't mention where it gets its data from or which search engine it is talking about.

Note: if other popular search engines provide this feature, I would be interested in those as well.